# Daily rituals to be performed by a Sudra according to Hindu dharma

Tags: puranas, dharma

Several daily rituals/practices have been suggested/directed to be followed by Brahman (Brahmins) by holy scriptures in Hinduism.
Likewise, what daily rituals have been suggested especially to Sudras to perform on a daily basis. Please name the authoritative scripture on the subject.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Shudra must perform Shraddha on a daily basis. (A Shraddha or rite to deceased ancestors can be performed daily, monthly or even yearly).

Because, the performance of Shraddha makes use of the Mantra "Swadha", which every one, including the Shudra, can utter, as says the following verse:

> Manu Smriti 2.172. (He who has not been initiated) should not
>   pronounce (any) Vedic text **excepting (those required for) the
>   performance of funeral rites,** since he is on a level with a Sudra
>   before his birth from the Veda.

And, according Yajnavalkya Smriti's Chapter 1 verses given below, a Shudra should perform the Pancha Maha Yajnas ( Deva, Pitru, Rishi, Manushya and Bhuta Yajnas) as well, using the Mantra "Namas" or Namaha.

> The service of the twice born, is the duty of a Sudrah, if he can not
>   maintain himself by that, he may become a tradesman, or he may
>   maintain himself with various works of art, but he should always do
>   good unto the twice born (120)
>
> [He should be] devotedly attached to his wife, be protector of
>   servants and **given to the performance of Shraddha. With the recitation
>   of the Mantram- Namas, he should perform the five Yajnas**. (121)
>
> Abstention from cruelty, truthfulness, not stealing, purity, control
>   of the senses, charity, mercy, self-restraint and forgiveness, are the
>   religious practices for all. (122)

Apart from the ones mentioned above, a Shudra is not required to perform any other rituals on a daily basis.

Comment: Thanks Rickross. I would like to further add this “For ordinary men, at least five yajïas, known as Panca-maha-yajna, are necessary.” - Bhagavad Gita 3.12