Are Shudras required to perform Shraddha ritual?
Are Shudras required to perform Shraddha ritual?
Or is the Shraddha ritual only meant to be performed by the first three varnas (Brahmin, Kshatriya and Vaishya)?

Yes they should .. see the following it answers your question --- https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/26300/4732
